# uploading video to s3 with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

Hi im trying to upload a video to s3 and display it using flowplayer

my flowplayer crashes because the numbers are added at the back of the url of video src

```
<div class="flowplayer" style="width: 624px; height: 260px; ">
   <video src="http://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/psyched-sg-store/624x260.mp4?1350552718"></video>
</div>
```

this breaks my flowplayer , but clicking on the link after view source brings me to the video

```
<div class="flowplayer" style="width: 624px; height: 260px; ">
   <video src="http://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/psyched-sg-store/624x260.mp4"></video>
</div>
```

this works

i set up my paperclip like this

```
# /config/initializer/s3.rb
# if you're using sg buckets
Paperclip.interpolates(:s3_sg_url) { |attachment, style|
   "#{attachment.s3_protocol}//s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/#{attachment.bucket_name}/#{attachment.path(style).gsub(%r{^/},
   "")}"
   }
```

in my model..

```
  has_attached_file :attached_video,:storage => :s3,
       :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
       :path => "/:filename",
       :url  => ":s3_sg_url"

       def attached_video_url
           if attached_video.file?
            attached_video.url
          else
            nil
        end    
      end
```

i also set up my s3.yml

```
development:
  bucket: psyched-sg-store
  access_key_id: xx
  secret_access_key: xx
test:
  bucket: psyched-sg-store
  access_key_id: xx
  secret_access_key: x
production:
  bucket: psyched-sg-store
  access_key_id: xx
  secret_access_key: xx
```

whats wrong? why are the numbers appearing behind the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those numbers are anti-caching timestamps. If you want to get rid of them, add `:use_timestamp => false` to your model's attachment setup, as in:

```
has_attached_file :attached_video,:storage => :s3,
       :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
       :path => "/:filename",
       :url  => ":s3_sg_url",
       :use_timestamp => false
```